# Understanding polarization and magnetization intuitively?

Tags: electromagnetism, dipole, dipole-moment

I am trying to develop a more intuitive understanding of the field produced by magnetization and polarization.

[image]

I have the following image, and I can derive it from Maxwell's equations what the fields inside and outside are given uniform polarization, but is there a way to understand them more intuitively?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking about why the fields point in the opposite direction inside while in the same direction outside the sphere.

The source of the apparent inconsistency is, on the one hand, the prevalent 20th century view of the *macroscopic* B-field being primary and the H-field being secondary derived quantity (exactly the opposite way as it was viewed in the 19th century), and the underlying structural and physical differences between the E-field and B or H-field.

The source of the microscopic electric field is electric charge distribution of individual electric charges that come in two flavors. There are no magnetic charges but the are natural elementary magnetic dipoles and the source of the microscopic magnetic field is both moving charges and elementary magnetic dipoles.

The macroscopic electric and magnetic fields are spatial and time averages of these microscopic fields and the averaging results in two pairs of *macroscopic* fields, from the microscopic electric field one gets E and D, from the microscopic magnetic field B and H. Neither is more fundamental than the other, both are averages of microscopic fields, but since $\text{div} \mathbf B=0$ always and in relativity E and B transform together physicists prefer it over H that transforms with D. Instead, engineers think of the H as physicists used to before relativity, because its source is the field-induced magnetic inhomogeneity of the dipole distribution that formally behave as if they were real charges and H is therefore similar to E and they think of it as the "real" thing. But neither is the real thing,  all are averages of the *real* things.

On the right you plotted the B field but not the induced H field that because of the induced surface *charges* would look very similar to the E field on the left. This was a choice not rooted in physics but more in tradition or psychology.